# angular url getting changed when the page is reloaded with query params

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Hope everyone is safe :)

I am using angular 9 and I have an url which uses query params and they are working fine as expected

**My URL:**

http://localhost:4200/#/playbook/columnView?taskType=KEYPOINT&taskTypeId=d1b404d7-afa2-42cd-9f1b-5cc8125c0bfb&taskBlockId=ad96069c-cbb2-4a65-8b75-175bf1977282

But when I reload my page using browser reload button, the url is adding some %3, how to fix them

**Reloaded URL:**

http://localhost:4200/#/playbook/columnView%3FtaskType%3DKEYPOINT&taskTypeId%3Dd1b404d7-afa2-42cd-9f1b-5cc8125c0bfb&taskBlockId%3Dad96069c-cbb2-4a65-8b75-175bf1977282

**My routing**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PlaybookEntryComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'columnView',
                component: ColumnviewComponent
            }
        ],
    },
];
```

Comment: How are you reloading the URL?  Is this a browser action you are taking?  Or something you're doing in code?

Comment: no just browser action

Comment: Can you show me your routing configuration?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using the hash strategy?

Comment: Yes after reload If I dont use the hash strategy it takes back to homepage @MikeOne

Comment: Updated my question with route config @Bozhinovski

Comment: If it redirects you to the homepage you should correctly set your routes :)

Comment: No I think that is default behaviour how angular works @GuyT. Angular also has some docs how to setup server to not redirecting to homepage on reload, but I cant configure server so I used hash strategy

Comment: You can try something like this in order to fix ur issue:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: But shld I decode uri and again call that url every time? Is it a best practice?

Comment: @GvsAkhil No, that is not how it works. If you have defined your routes correctly the correct component will show up

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml Can u check that url @GuyT

Comment: @GvsAkhil This is something totally different..

Comment: Oh okkk then what’s the mistake in my code  @GuyT

Answer (score 0):

While reloading **Your browser will encode the URL**,

So in that case for `? - %3F`

Comment: No way to fix it?

Comment: Ok will change them as normal params